# Making complex new variables

Tags: syntax, spss

I have troubles finding a solution to the following problem:

I have an age variable (e.g. 18, 20, 56) and a date when the survey was taken (2012). What I want to do is the following: if the respondent is 10 years old I need to make 10 categories of age with 0 and 1 when the respondent was not existing or alive: so new variable age2002 = 1, age2003 = 1, ... age2012 = 1 but age2000 = 0 and age1990 = 0.
How can I do this is in spss syntax for every respondent? I have many varying ages but the year of the survey is always the same.

Comment: I somehwat understand the logic of what you are asking here but at the same time don't understand under what circumstances data in this format would be at all useful?

Comment: Variable construction, combining data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for all the ages from 1 to 100:

```
do repeat NewVr=age1912 to age2012/vl=1912 to 2012.
 compute  NewVr=(2012-age<=vl).
end repeat.
execute.
```

if you only want all the ages between 1 to 10 and then 2000, 1990, 1980 etc':

```
do repeat NewVr=age1970 age1980 age1990 age2000 age2002 to age2012
          /vl=1970 1980 1990 2000 2002 to 2012.
 compute  NewVr=(2012-age<=vl).
end repeat.
execute.
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know how to stop making this variable depending on survey year. For example if 2012 is a variable that is the survey year (with many different years). After the survey year, it should not make a 1 but a zero for a particular respondent because i don't know that he is still alive after the survey year. So for example, if 2012 is the survey year for a particular respondent, age2013 should be zero.

Comment: As David Marso suggested, you should add some explanation what you need this for - to help generalize this for other users and maybe hear some alternatives.

Comment: In the DO REPEAT replace 2012 with SurveyYear. Then add, after the COMPUTE command:   
  
'if vl > SurveyYear NewVr=0.'

Comment: Thanks, I also find this workable (survey year - age <= vl and vl <= survey year)

Answer (score 1):

What is the actual problem you are attempting to solve?  Creating a bunch (100)  0/1 dummy variables doesn't seem like a very sound data management practice.
If you do go with the suggested

```
DO REPEAT ...
compute  NewVr=(2012-age<=vl).
....
```

I would rewrite that as

```
COMPUTE newvar= ( (2012-age ) LE v1 ).
```

just seems clearer to parse in my brain.